# Bonding 2 interfaces inside a linux network namespace

Tags: linux-networking, high-availability, bonding, network-namespace, network-teaming

I'd like to be able to bond/aggregate 2 interfaces inside a Linux network namespace.

The configuration I'm working with is the following:

- On the root linux net stack I have two physical ethernet interfaces:

  - eth0
  - eth1
- And then I have a network namespace that has 2 interfaces:

  - ethX0 that is bridged to physical eth0
  - ethX1 that is bridged to physical eth1

I'd like to bond ethX0 and ethX1 inside the network namespace, either with 802.3ad or active-backup.

But bonding on Linux works at the physical interface level and I can't seem to make this work, although I don't see why (at the frame level) it couldn't be done ? I can create a net-ns *over* a bond, but not a bond *over* a net-ns.

I can't bond the eth0 and eth1 physical interfaces, because I want to be able to adress them separately for a myriad other applications, but I'd like only ethX0 and ethX1 to be bonded.

Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: Is this setup intended to experiment for example with failovers, or is there an other specific reason in mind? For an experiment, or maybe to have similar setups across different environments I can understand (and might have an answer), else I fail to see what's the goal of this.

Comment: Hi, this is for an operational system. I'm overlaying lots of VLANs and network namespaces. I need for a tiny part of the system, to interconnect with a customer that asks that Ethernet links that go out of the PC be bonded. I can't bond the physical interfaces as, for other streams I have to control precisely on which Ethernet port data goes out.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found was to use teams. Great recent Linux api, works in network namespaces and behavior can be controlled from userland. Great stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Some people seem to use `teams` for this but that's not really required. For Ubuntu/Debian systems you can just edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and do something like this to use native kernel support instead:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# 2 x 10 Gbps LACP link:
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
bond-mode 802.3ad
bond-miimon 100
bond-lacp-rate 1
bond-slaves enp1s0f0 enp1s0f1

# 10 Gbps port 1:
auto enp1s0f0
iface enp1s0f0 inet manual
bond-master bond0

# 10 Gbps port 2:
auto enp1s0f1
iface enp1s0f1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

# VLAN 395:
auto bond0.395
iface bond0.395 inet static
address 11.22.33.44
netmask 255.255.255.224
gateway 11.22.33.1
dns-nameservers 11.22.33.1 11.22.33.2
dns-search example.com
vlan-raw-device bond0
```

This allows tapping `tcpdump` to whatever part you need to debug. In this example `bond0` is the raw traffic with VLAN tags over two connections, `enp1s0f0` and `enp1s0f1` are the raw ports transferring LACP/802.3ad traffic and `bond0.395` is the logical network without VLAN tags. Obviously, the correct VLAN number depends on your upstream configuration, the `395` is just an example.

See https://wiki.debian.org/Bonding for details.

Comment: Thanks for this. I can tcpdump on the enp1s0f0 and enp1s0f1 interfaces but can I send/receive packets and bind sockets on them?

Comment: Haven't ever tried to send anything using those, just via the bond0.395. I would assume that if you define `address` for those devices it should be fine.